# Automatic Update IoT Core Application

Tags: c#, azure, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to build a C# application that would update itself on a RaspberryPi using Windows IoT Core. I've done this before in NodeJs on Linux using a repo in the cloud, the app was simply re-writing itself.

Is there such a feature already implemented on the IoT Core or in Azure or do I need to program my own solution?
I won't have physical access to the device or it's network once it is deployed.

Comment: I'm not aware of such feature implemented in IoT Core. But rewriting the application as it is running will probably not be possible. Your application will have to check for updates, if some are available, download/launch an updater app, and terminate itself. The updater app will then have to download the new version of your application and launch it again.

Comment: Yes if I go this route and there is no built in feature, I'll probably have a Service running on the side to Start/Stop/Update my main application. Node was a no-brainer but c# requires a bit more structure, I agree.

Comment: You'd think so, but it is not quite that simple. You see the iot-core is a secure platform with sandbox and a whole lot of security features. Thus, downloading an app and starting it really means downloading a certified app package and installing it using the supported AppInstall oemcustomization.cmd features. This worked for us, until iot-core automatic base OS updates started, at which point the base system is pulling the proverbial rug out from under -- we are working with Microsoft to resolve this. See below. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

we are in precisely the same situation. There is nothing yet at the level that can be found, for example, in debian. However, there are preview (very early) options in the [iot-hub space](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-iot-hub-device-management/) moving in this direction. Also, you can create a custom image and have it updated from the windows store via the oem program (currently costs around 70 $/year). We are investigating both and, in the meantime, have written our own over-air-update. However, our custom update is now being hindered by the automatic updates of iot-core. [Here is the thread with the current "play-by-play"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1022128-8fde-48e9-ab38-2e84a03b1ae1/windows-10-iot-core-pro-licenses?forum=WindowsIoT&prof=required) as far as I can see. Hope this helps!